# How to let Chrome Remote Desktop run with encrypted /home before login

Tags: encryption, remote-desktop, ecryptfs, remote-login

### Background:

- I have a headless system put on a public place. I installed Chrome
  Remote Desktop on it, so that it  can automatically launch several desktop
  applications after boot, and I can connect remotely to check the status.
- Since the system is accessible by non-authorized folks, I want to encrypt /home directly for primitive security ( I
  know encrypting /home only is not TRUE secure, but it is good
  enough for me to stop some casual glance only).
- I followed the    guides [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/how-to-encrypt-home-folder-in-ubuntu.html) to encrypt /home with
  eCryptfs.    However, the    encryption broke the remote desktop
  service, which    worked    perfectly before encryption.
- The reason is, chrome remote desktop service can not access config
  files before login, which locates in ~/.config/. So it fails at
  start.

### My question:

Is it possible to allow Chrome Remote Desktop (or more generally, any service that runs with the privilege of specific user) to access encrypted /home directory before user login?  I do not insist on eCryptfs. Any lighter (less secure) tool is also acceptable.

### Some more information:

1. They system locates behind some NAT gateway, and I have no control on the gateway. So I can not access with ssh.
2. I need reboot the system remotely from time to time, so full-disk encryption is not an option.

Comment: One solution may be to locate `.config` outside the `/home` directory, for example, in `/etc/myconfig/.config`. then setup Chrome to look for config there instead of the default location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible if you have an encrypted home directory.

You don't have the luxury of 'running things as the user' if the user's information and data are encrypted and need accessed.

If your `/home` directory is encrypted, you can't access it until you decrypt it - which you have to do manually from the system with logon.  That's kind of the point of encrypted home - your data is encrypted and you have to manually login to unlock it.

Encrypted home will break services such as these that run in 'userspace'.

Comment: Got the point. Thank you for clarifying